# Is there a way to get the next letter in the alphabet

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I am trying to create a method which takes in a character from the alphabet (for example 'd') and return the next character from the alphabet (aka. e). How can I do that?

Comment: What do you consider the "next character" for `z`?

Comment: Try following :            string input = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
            string output = string.Join("",input.Select(x => (char)((byte)x + 1)));

Comment: This is a surprisingly difficult task to do well  What alphabet? (US English / ASCII: easy;  European languages: require specification; Japanese Kanji: hard) What letter comes after ç (lower case c with cedilla)? d? What comes after N? O, or in Spanish, Ñ?  You need to specify both character set and collation to make this a meaningful question.  If your character set is ASCII and your collation is "binary", it's easy. Otherwise ... read about character sets and collations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can walk the ascii table:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var letter = 'd';
    Console.WriteLine((char)(letter + 1));
}
```

Comment: and for `z`? what about `Ñ`? `曜`?

Comment: @DetectivePikachu ask OP.